# Faut-il écrire « rien agit sur le corps » ou bien « rien n'agit sur le corps » ?

Tags: négation

Faut-il écrire ?

> Rien agit sur le corps

ou bien

> Rien n'agit sur le corps

Comment: Would you write/say "rien ne bouge" or "rien bouge" (for example)?

Comment: Exemple 2 est la bonne réponse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit de la seconde solution:

> Rien n'agit sur le corps

Utilisés en début de phrase en tant que pronoms sujets, rien et personne sont toujours suivis de ne/n'

> Personne n'aime se lever tôt
>
> Rien n'est pire

Comment: merci beaucoup pour l'information

Answer (score 0):

Je rajouterai autre chose. Le "n'" est un utilisé pour une négation, il est lié avec le "rien". On pourrai très bien dire "Cela n'agit pas sur le corps". Attention à ne pas se faire induire en erreur avec la liaison sonore.